# Copy text only, excluding formatting etc

Tags: windows, clipboard

Is it possible to copy just text to clipboard?

Currently I have to paste and recopy out of Notepad or go through the pain of paste special (if it's being pasted into Office).

Comment: where are you copying out of, and where are you pasting into ?

Comment: Webpages, Office etc. More than one thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could give [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) a try, I am using a script from [this](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/77815-copy-text-and-remove-all-formatting/) suggestion and it works.

```
F2::
Clipboard=%Clipboard%
Sleep, 100
Send ^v
Return
```

If you save this piece of code to a file with the ending .ahk and open it with autohotkey, it will run in the background and whenever you press F2 (or any other hotkey you can define), it will remove formatting and paste the text. You could also define Ctrl+V as a hotkey, so it will paste everything automatically without formatting as long as the script is running.

Comment: Good idea, not practical for me on a corperate system.

Comment: You can run autohotkey without installation, it's a standalone executable if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try [PureText](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/). It does not replace the default paste functions but I quickly got used to using it's default of Win+V. Gave me the freedom to keep Ctrl+V should I want to retain the formatting. It is a portable app so no installation required so you maybe OK in your corporate environment.

[image]

Comment: Be on alert, that this is a compiled program which can do anything on your system. Where is the source code?